# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install, node-sass

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)

I faced this issue when I used the latest version of node.js i.e, 12.6.0 and npm version 6.9.0.

which version of node-sass is compatible with above mentioned node and npm versions.

node-sass version: 4.5.3

Answer (score 5):

Use the following command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

You likely copied the node_modules from a Windows or OSX system. Rebuilding it builds the right version for your system.

Comment: This failed miserably - so many errors!
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/sobs/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/sobs/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1

Comment: @muztheaxe - Every error in Node looks like it failed miserably, so much output and red `ERR`. Though, this error shows not much. Is it an excerpt?

Comment: I had to get some help to fix this.  This was a fresh install of everything, however it was Debian 9 rather than Debian 10.  We started again (from a fresh install) with Debian 10 and this then worked.

Answer (score 1):

We list this at the top of the README https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimium-support
For Node 12, you need node-sass 4.12

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to solve this issue.

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```